# VS Install Crashes and Burns

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've never seen this before.  Please can somebody shed some light on it for me.  I've just done a clean install of Vista Business 64, followed by Firefox, followed by VS 2008 SP1, from an MSDN DVD.  Late in the installation - I wasn't watching so didn't see when - I suddenly got a screenful of *fail*.

The first message in the error log is:

```
setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293
```

Google yields very, very few relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done this straight after installing Vista,  without a restart.  After a restart and 39 updates, I ran the install again and it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

From what I found, HRESULT -2147023293 has to do with dlls not being registered properly in Vista. I haven't had to do this in a LONG time, but what you may want to do is try running the installer as Administrator (right click on setup.exe, Run As Administrator command).

http://forums.techarena.in/vista-administration/1039438.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I was running as admin.